# How to use SQL Delight in android Electrical Eel?Connecting with the SQLdelight plugin failed

Tags: android-studio, sqldelight

I updated android studio to the electric eel but after that I am unable to use SQLDelight plugin.

It was showing me this :- Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1)

Then after that I downloaded EAP plugin for android studio Electric Eel still it is not working. It is giving me this error.:-  `Connecting with the SQLdelight plugin failed try building from the command line`